# Tomcat 6 with Java 8 giving JSP compilation error

Tags: tomcat, servlets, java-8

I was using tomcat 6 and just upgraded to Java jdk1.8.0_92. But when I run my web application on tomcat server. It gives this error.

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

When I open my url localhost:8080

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 logs.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

I cannot change Tomcat 6, because it is inbuild version of Pentaho BI server.
Is there any possible way to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: You can install both jdk versions (1.7 and 1.8). Then you can start and run tomcat with 1.7 and do your other stuff with 1.8.

Comment: You don't even need to install a jdk a jre 1.7 should be sufficient to run the tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your jdk upgrade.
You have the following two errors:
**Unable to compile class for JSP**
and
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp**

Most likely, you have errors in your index.jsp file so it cannot be compiled.
Make sure you do not have any errors in your jsp files.